# PHP - curl_multi gives a 400 Bad request

Tags: php, api, curl, put

With my code I receive data from a website. I want to transfer this data into database fields via a REST-API. This should work with cURL (PUT). So I need several cURL's run in my script to fill different database fields. For this I used the example code from php.net (http://php.net/manual/de/function.curl-multi-init.php). Unfortunately I only get a "400 Bad request - Your browser sent an invalid request". What am I doing wrong?

The Code i receive data

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$User_Agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0';

$url = "http://hub.culturegraph.org/entityfacts/118540238";
$url2 = "https://bpk.bs.picturemaxx.com/api/v1/editing/classifications/42/elements/2156190";
$url3 = "https://bpk.bs.picturemaxx.com/api/v1/editing/classifications/42/elements/2156191";

$request_headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$request_headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
$request_headers[] = 'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3';
$request_headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8';
$request_headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding:  gzip, deflate, identity';
$request_headers[] = 'Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3';
$request_headers[] = 'X-picturemaxx-api-key: key';
$request_headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer token";
$request_headers[] = 'Expect: ';

// build the individual requests, but do not execute them
$ch = curl_init($url);
//  Initiate curl
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $User_Agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");

$result = curl_exec($ch); // Performs the Request, with specified curl_setopt() options (if any).
curl_close($ch);
// Closing

$data = json_decode($result, true);
```

With the following code the data to transfer are determined, inserted into the form to transfer and json_encode.

```
$alternativData = array();
foreach($data['variantName'] as $alternativ) {
//echo $alternativ . " ; ";
$alternativData[] = $alternativ;
}


$dataj = array (
'classification_element_parent_id' => 0,
'classification_element_matchcode' => '',
'classification_element_foreignref' => '',
'localized' => 
array (
'en-us' => 
array (
'classification_element_name' => '',
),
'de-de' => 
array (
'classification_element_name' => substr(implode(' ; ', $alternativData),0 ,10000),
),
),
);
$data_json = json_encode($dataj);
$request_headers[] = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_json);


$dataj2 = array (
'classification_element_parent_id' => 2156190,
'classification_element_matchcode' => '',
'localized' => 
array (
'en-us' => 
array (
'classification_element_name' => '',
),
'de-de' => 
array (
'classification_element_name' => $data['dateOfBirth'],
),
),
);

$data_json2 = json_encode($dataj2);
$request_headers[] = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_json2);
```

Then follows the curl_multi_init which leads to the 400 Bad request.

```
$ch_2 = curl_init($url2);
$ch_3 = curl_init($url3);


curl_setopt( $ch_2, CURLOPT_URL, $url2 );
curl_setopt($ch_2, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $User_Agent);
curl_setopt($ch_2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
curl_setopt($ch_2, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_setopt($ch_2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch_2, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch_2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);

curl_setopt( $ch_3, CURLOPT_URL, $url3 );
curl_setopt($ch_3, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $User_Agent);
curl_setopt($ch_3, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
curl_setopt($ch_3, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_setopt($ch_3, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch_3, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch_3, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json2);

// build the multi-curl handle, adding both $ch
$mh = curl_multi_init();
curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch_2);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch_3);

$active = null;
// Handles ausführen
do {
$mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
if (curl_multi_select($mh) == -1) {
usleep(100);
}
do {
$mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
}

//close the handles
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch_2);
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch_3);
curl_multi_close($mh);

$response_1 = curl_multi_getcontent($ch_2);
$response_2 = curl_multi_getcontent($ch_3);
echo "$response_1 $response_2"; // output results 

var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch_2));
var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch_3));
```

Thank you in advance for any help and advice.

Comment: Why do you `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` when you end up echoing `application/json`?

Comment: Because I want the output in the browser, insofar as I need one, as text.

Comment: Regardless. You send JSON to a browser with content type `application/json`. You'll still get your text

Comment: Even if i change the header to "application/json" it doesn't change the 400 bad request.

Comment: Yes that's not the cause of the problem, just something you should change anyway. a 400 means you've sent bad data across, not what they expected

Comment: What does `curl_error($ch_2)` give you? Or `$ch_3`?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: Ok i do that. Thank you. More ideas?

Comment: Then i get this message: "Curl error: easy handle already used in multi handle"

Comment: just noticed `$mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);`. But `$active = null`

Comment: So what does that mean? I took it from php.net like this.

Comment: And if I get information with "var_dump(curl_multi_info_read($mh));" about the current transfer I get this message: "bool(false)". Any ideas?

Comment: I found the problem. I used the code line "$request_headers[] = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_json2);" several times due to an earlier error message. The API does not need this information.